# Format DateTime in custom UTC Format using JSTL

Tags: java, datetime, jstl

I like to format my DateTime in JSTL with providing timeZone. But It Does not work perfectly. I Went through lot of suggestion but can't reach the goal. What I tried this is

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${timeSlot.getStartTime()}" 
pattern="HH:mm" timeZone="UTC-6" var="startTime" />
```

*Edit*:-

value="08:41:00" for `timeSlot.getStartTime()`

Any help or suggestion.

**Update:**

after using `input type="time"` it gives me like that

[image: img]

Comment: Can you please share the output / error you got?

Comment: Basically it's not showing any error. IT's not convert the date in desired format.

Comment: okay. At least share the date  value coming from `timeSlot.getStartTime()`

Comment: please try after adding  `type = "time"` and share the result. I am sure this should work.

Comment: `value="08:41:00"` for `timeSlot.getStartTime() `

Comment: please try what I have suggested.

Comment: it's not working :(

Comment: share the logs with failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation and suggestions from `SO Q&A` I have solved the `timezone` issue what I faced in another way. Let me share what I have done.

- When I request for the page I also bind a **Local TimeZone Offset**
  value with `HttpServletRequest`. This local TimeZone Offset value is
  calculated with `javascript`.

**js code** for getting local timezone offset value.

```
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
var timeZone = offset / -60;
```

- Than I just have added the `TimeZone Offset` which data I fetched from the `database`.

**Java Code**

```
String timeZoneValue = request.getParameter("timeZone");
timeZoneValue = Long.valueOf(timeZone).longValue(); // convert string to long value.
// get the calendar instances
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(time); // set the time which get from DB
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, timeZoneValue.intValue() * 60); // added the timezone offset.
// formatting  the time
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");  
parseTime = simpleDateFormat.format(cal.getTime()); 
Date newDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(parseTime);
```

This mechanism works for me perfectly. Thank you.

**Note:** In database when I always saved time as `UTC` format.